# Change in model not detected

Tags: python, django

I added this module to my application: https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz.
The module has a submodule named `quiz`, which has a model class called `Question`.

I want to change that class so that it corresponds to a user so I added this to the submodules's `models.py`:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        verbose_name=_("UserId")
    )
```

I am now trying to generate the corresponding database migrations.

However, when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` nothing happens.

Why is that the case?

Comment: How about `python manage.py makemigrations quiz`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works or nor. The first time I ran the command some migrations were made, but then I changed that field and now no migrations are generated any more.

Answer (score 0):

You claim some migrations were made. Well probably Foreign Key was created successfully. If you added some parameters to Foreign Key, this might not be needed to migrate database, but Django will take that change into account.
It is probably your case. Try to run `python manage.py migrate quiz` and see if it works as you wanted in the first place. If not, let us know what setting is missing.